# How can I do equivalent to actingAs() when not using Laravel Auth

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, cartalyst-sentinel

All documentation that I have found refers to the Laravel helper `actingAs()` but this requires me to be using Laravel's native Auth package and I'm using Cartalyst's Sentinel and so can't use `actingAs()`.

Has anyone found a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `login` method of Sentinel facade.

```
$user = Sentinel::getUserById(1);
$rememberMe = true;
Sentinel::login($user, $rememberMe);
```

You can also use `setUser` method of Sentinel facade. Note this doesn't log the user in.

```
$user = Sentinel::getUserById(1);
Sentinel::setUser($user);
```

Comment: How to use a repository result with actingAs()?. My error is Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase::actingAs() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given,